# Aligning buttons horizontally that are within divs

Tags: html, css, button, alignment

```css
.button {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: inherit;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.input-div {
  vertical-align: top;
  }
```

```html
<div class="form-group  field-plan">
    <label for="plan" class="col-sm-3 control-label">
     Current Plan
    </label>
    <div class="input-div col-sm-9">
     <p class="form-control-static control-field-plan">
        20 alerts per day <br> 
                       0 out of 20 used
                      <span class="button">
                        <button class="change-button btn btn-success">
                          Change Plan
                        </button>
                      </span>
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group payment_method field-payment_method">
    <label for="payment_method" class="col-sm-3 control-label">
     Payment
    </label>
    <div class="input-div col-sm-9">
     <p class="form-control-static control-field-payment_method">
                      Visa 4242 <br>
                      Next payment due: 2016-15-05
                      <span class="button">
                        <button class="update-card btn btn-success">
                          Update Card
                        </button>
                      </span>
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
```

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group  field-plan">
    <label for="plan" class="col-sm-3 control-label">
        Current Plan
    </label>
    <div class="input-div col-sm-9">
        <p class="form-control-static control-field-plan">
            {{get_current_plan current_customer.plan}}
            <button class="change-button btn btn-success">
                Change Plan
            </button>

        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group payment_method field-payment_method">
    <label for="payment_method" class="col-sm-3 control-label">
        Payment
    </label>
    <div class="input-div col-sm-9">
        <p class="form-control-static control-field-payment_method">
            {{get_payment_method current_customer.payment_method}}
            <button class="update-card btn btn-success">
                Update Card
            </button>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My app displays text in the two {{ ... }} that are before the buttons.
The amount of text varies and can be over several lines sometimes.

The location of the buttons seem to be determined by the last line of the text, so it varies greatly where the buttons are placed, and it doesn't look good.

I know very little about css, but have been unable to place the buttons correctly adjacent to the first line of text in each div.

Can anyone guide me as to css for this?

Comment: Can you post an image of the desired result?

Comment: margin: auto; centers things within its parent element.

Comment: At a guess, this is a `vertical-align:top` issue BUT questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to make a stack snippet

Comment: I added a stack snippet. I tried the above suggestions but they didn't seem to work. (I'm a CSS newbie, sorry)

Answer (score 1):

Changed a little bit structure of HTML. By the way, I post bid on your project for this task on Upwork

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group  field-plan">
                <label for="plan" class="col-sm-3 control-label">
                    Current Plan
                </label>
                <div class="input-div col-sm-9">
                    <p class="form-control-static control-field-plan">
                       20 alerts per day <br>   
                       0 out of 20 used
                      <span class="button">
                        <button class="change-button btn btn-success">
                          Change Plan
                        </button>
                      </span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group payment_method field-payment_method">
                <label for="payment_method" class="col-sm-3 control-label">
                    Payment
                </label>
                <div class="input-div col-sm-9">
                    <p class="form-control-static control-field-payment_method">
                      Visa 4242 <br>
                      Next payment due: 2016-15-05
                      <span class="button">
                        <button class="update-card btn btn-success">
                          Update Card
                        </button>
                      </span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .button {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        right:0;
    }
    .form-group{
      position:relative;
      width:300px;
    }
    .input-div {
      vertical-align: top;
      }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fabian89/ndgx1drc/

Answer (score 0):

The way i see it, there are two easy ways for you to do this.

The easiest and most trivial way would be to create a 2x2 table. Cells' styling and size can be easily manipulated with CSS, the same way you did with `.button`.

The other way I see it, you could add CSS for your `input-div col-sm-9` class, using `text-align` for vertical alignment, for instance.

Check out http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp to learn more about CSS use. They have great examples and tutorials.

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: text-align doesn't seem to work for vertical alignment. I tried "vertical-align" instead but it seems to have no effect. I modified the above stack snippet with vertical-align but as you see there is no effect. The other suggestion is to create a 2x2 table for this. Unfortunately I cannot do that since the html is auto-generated by another tool. Only option I have is to use css to handle it :-(

Comment: I'm not sure if this will change anything, but you could try placing the `<div>` containing your `buttons` **outside** your `<div>` which contains text. Perhaps those `<div>` are restricting your actions towards the `buttons` alignment.

Answer (score 0):

If I am clear what you want, I would suggest to add some top margin for .button, for example: margin-top: 35px or 2.7em.